# Parsing Content of Array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have:

```
array1 = [{'x': 1}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 5}]
```

And I want to parse the number values after the `:` into this array like:

```
[1,2,3,5]
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: is the input a string or an array?

Comment: let result = array1.map(obj => obj.x);

Comment: `array1.map(i => i.x)`

Comment: @briosheje so the input is an array.

Comment: I removed the Angular tag, it has nothing to do with Angular, unless you wonder how to do the computation in a template or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) function to create a new array.

```js
array1 = [{'x': 1}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 5}] 
array2 = array1.map(o=>o.x);
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` for your requirement

```
let result = array1.map(c=>c.x);
```

```js
array1 = [{'x': 1}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 5}] 

let result = array1.map(c=>c.x);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: But how does it work? I get array.map loops through and takes value=> and does something to it.

what does the object.x part do?

Comment: @my_mistakes the object.x part filters each value of 'x'

Answer (score 0):

```
array1 = [{'x': 1}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 5}] 

const values = array1.map(object => object.x)

console.log(values)
```

Comment: Consider adding some commentary to your post to assist readers on what you are attempting to present with your code.

Answer (score 0):

using Plain JS,

```js
array1 = [{'x': 1}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 5}] 
out = []
for (i in array1) {
  out.push(array1[i]['x'])
}
console.log(out)
// using array map
op = array1.map(i => i.x)
console.log(op)
```